# TeamCity swap configuration files

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity

I have been using CC.NET for a while and decided to try Team City.
The initial and default configuration is very easy, but how do I swap configuration files after code is checked out and before unit tests are run.

I am using TFS, NUnit. 
1. When working locally I have configuration file pointing to local server.
2. On the build server TeamCity get's notification that I have checked-in code and builds new version. 
3. Server runs unit tests

When on 3rd step server runs unit tests I need to swap configuration files that are pointing to other servers, not the ones I am using locally.

How do you accomplish this task in TeamCity?

Thanks,
Edijs

Answer (score 0):

You can setup DEPENDENT Builds in TeamCity.  If your new version compiles, it can trigger your Unit Test build.

I usually run this via different NANT files instead.  Based upon my NANT Target, I can get different behavior from the same build, and that is what I specify in TeamCity.